# Send excel table as an attachment

Tags: vba, email, send, bulk

Need your help.

I have an excel sheet of item master with stock availability and store email address are in heralding cells vertically & under the email address there are Y & N mapping done against entire style code in the in the item master.

I am looking for a VBA code that should filter database one by one for the email address mentioned in the heading cells and copy table where Y found and send the table as an attachment.

Subject would be "Updated SOH". Kindly refer database sample mentioned below.

[image: Item Master]

Answer (score 0):

I use a macro for sending emails all the time, here is the unedited code:

```
Sub SendEmail(Optional ToAddresses As String, Optional CcAddresses As String, _
Optional BccAddresses As String, Optional Subject As String, _
Optional Body As String, Optional AttachFiles As Variant = False, Optional AutoSend As Boolean = False)
'Adapted from https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail4.htm

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = ToAddresses
        .CC = CcAddresses
        .Bcc = BccAddresses
        .Subject = Subject
        
        If Body Like "*</*>*" Then
            .HtmlBody = Body
        Else
            .Body = Body
        End If
        
        If Not AttachFiles = False Then
            If IsArray(AttachFiles) Then
                For x = LBound(AttachFiles) To UBound(AttachFiles)
                    .Attachments.Add (AttachFiles(x))
                Next
            Else
                .Attachments.Add (AttachFiles)
            End If
        End If
        
        If AutoSend = True Then
            .Send
        Else
            .Display
        End If
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

I can't see your screenshot due to a problem with my browser (sorry), but hopefully this should help as at some point in your loop in another sub you can just do something like this;

```
Call SendEmail (ToAddresses:= "someone@example.com; someoneelse@exmpl.com", _
        Subject:="Updated SOH", _
        Attachfiles:="c:/Users/Me/Documents/Myfile.txt", _
        Autosend:=True)
```

Some notes on the usage of the sub:

- All the arguments are optional
- To, CC and Bcc addresses are strings, if you want multiple addresses in any of those fields just separate them with a semicolon, like with any normal email.
- `Subject` and `Body` are strings too. Body can be HTML or plain t text, it will detect which.
- `Attachfiles` needs to be either a string, or a one-dimensional string array (if attaching multiple files). It should be the full filename including path - see the example I gave above.
- If `AutoSend` is `True`, the email will send without you ever seeing it (unless there's an error e.g. you didn't enter a valid address to send it to). If it's `False` (which it defaults to) it will show you the email instead and you can edit it before you hit the send button.

Hope that helps you or anyone reading this!! I find it really useful myself and there's no reason why others shouldn't benefit - as per the first comment in the code I adapted it from an online source anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot! here is the excel table as an example. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw6EH.jpg